# How can I set a For loop to read a list of URLs and scrape the data with Python Pandas Lib

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

This is my first Python script.  I'm currently trying to scrape data embedded in  HTML tables from  multiple urls which are located in a file called url-list.txt. 
 I've been successfully able to scrape the data I need using Python's Panda library from a single page, however I'm having the worst time trying  to do a simple for loop to load each url from the url-list.txt file to scrape the data from the remaining 100 or so urls. 
Here is what I've got so far.  You can see my attempt at the for loop commented out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```py
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

#url_list = "/home/awephuck/url-list.txt"
#for x in urls:

dfs = pd.read_html('http://example.com/dir1/file.html')
for df in dfs:
    print(df)
```

Comment: Broadly speaking, this question is probably not suitable for SO, and it would be better to google for "python for loops."

Comment: I think you should clarify if you need help writing a for loop (in which case take Mike's advice and google it) or if you need help looping through each line in a file and doing something with that data.

Answer (score 0):

Data **scrape** using HTML will be store in "list" not in  "Dataframe". 
All data will be store in first position in list.
create the Dataframe using list and attempt at the for loop  over index

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_html('https://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/banklist.html')
type(data)  # Data type of Scraped data
df=data[0]  #convert into dataframe
type(df)    
for i in df.index:    #loop using df.index
    print(df.iloc[i])
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ok, but I have a txt file with a couple hundred urls in it that need to be scraped, how would I loop all urls through the script.  Example, the 'https://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/banklist.html changes to https://www.bankofamerica.com/branches/index.html then to https://chase.com/branches

Comment: read input url forl txt file , loop above code on same.  

please provide the input list and expected output . will try to write the code

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.
[You should not post code as an image because:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: ValueError: No tables found

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make a list of the urls in your text file then loop around them.

ie:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as text:
    links = text.read().splitlines()

for url in links:
    #whatever you need to do
```

This assumes that each url is on its own line.

Answer (score 0):

Hate Python, ended up getting super hood with it but it works.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in `cat url-list.txt`; do
rm pyget.py

echo "import bs4 as bs" >> pyget.py
echo "import urllib.request" >> pyget.py
echo "import pandas as pd" >> pyget.py
echo  "dfs = pd.read_html($i)" >> pyget.py
echo "for df in dfs:" >> pyget.py
echo "  print(df)" >> pyget.py

python3 pyget.py >> clientdata.txt

done
```